# Wait for long process before considering ECS Fargate service as running

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, health-check

I'm have deployed an app with ECS Fargate that needs to download a large file to disk before it can start serving requests.

That file needs to be on disk, so I tried EFS, but it is too slow for my use case (its an embeded DB), so I have no other option than copying it to local disk on startup.

The application performs a `cp` from the EFS to local disk on startup, and than is supposed to but it usually takes about 10-20 minutes to copy since the file is large.

How can I configure ECS to consider my service "running" only after that command is done?

I don't want to change the health check, since I want to use it for regular health checking after the startup.

And I tried startPeriod, but the max value is 300s so that doesn't help.

Comment: Is this behind a load balancer?

Comment: No, but I cloud add one it it will help

Comment: I was just trying to understand what type of health checks you have available. How are you serving requests with an ECS Fargate task if it isn't behind a load balancer? Are these not HTTP requests?

Comment: This specific task is not open to the internet, its gets requests from other tasks (HTTP requests), and one is open to the internet behind a load balancer.

Comment: The maximum grace period for load balancer health checks is much higher than the docker health checks. You might try running it behind a private load balancer and using those health checks instead.

Comment: So you suggest to put a load balancer in front of my service, and use the lb health checks instead?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I suggested.